# Use go-file-rotatelogs in windows

Tags: windows, go

When I use [go-file-rotatelogs](https://github.com/lestrrat/go-file-rotatelogs) in Windows, I get the error

```
failed to rotate: 
failed to create new symlink: symlink 
system.log.20210723.log 
system.log.20210723.log_symlink: 
A required privilege is not held by the client .
```

Is it impossible to use go-file-rotatelogs in Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be [possible since Windows 10 Insiders build 14972 (windows 10 creators update ~ 1703)](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/185489)

Namely: you should be able to create symlink without administrator privilege.

Or, for testing, you could test your program from a CMD run as Administrator.

But the issue remains: this is likely linked to a privilege escalation required by the way Go implements symlink on Windows.

See "[`golang/go` issue 22874](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/22874): `os`: Symlink creation should work on Windows without elevation".

It is fixed in Go 1.11 with [commit c23afa9](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/c23afa9ddb1180b929ba09a7d96710677a2a4b45).

But if your Windows 10 is too old, or your current Go version is older than 1.11, you would get that error.